# Do Event Horizons Always Expand?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

I am reading Kip Thorne's book Black Holes and Time Warps.  In a section dedicated to Penrose, he discusses that Penrose and Hawking together postulated that the horizon of a black hole must always expand.  Is this before anyone discovered that BH's evaporated?  To me, it would be counter intuitive that a BH horizon would expand as it both increased in mass and then decreased in mass.

Comment: Does the book say that Penrose and Hawking were referring to classical general relativity? Black holes don't evaporate in classical general relativity. Hawking radiation can be derived without using a quantum theory of gravity, but that radiation leads to *evaporation* only in a quantum theory of gravity (if we exclude ad-hoc models that are not self-consistent).

Answer (score 2):

It's a theorem of classical GR (called Hawking's area theorem) that black hole event horizons can never shrink in size, assuming the null energy condition.

There's abundant evidence that black hole horizons do shrink and eventually disappear in quantum gravity due to Hawking radiation. It's sometimes claimed that this means the null energy condition is violated in quantum gravity, but it seems more likely that the apparent violation is an artifact of the semiclassical picture of black holes that's used to derive Hawking radiation (treating the black hole as classical and the radiation as quantum). The information loss problem suggests that there's something fundamentally wrong with that model.